# Django Selenium functional testing with celery in docker

Tags: django, docker, unit-testing, celery, django-celery

**BACKGROUND:** I have a Django application and i want to write tests for it. I have written a docker-compose.yml file so that i can be deployed on server quickly and easily. The application works with the help of celery and redis as its broker. The entire process of selenium testing is also being done via docker where i deploy selenium hub and nodes of chrome and firefox.

**PROBLEM:** When i run the `python manage.py test app_name.tests.test_forms` my fixtures are loaded and selenium connection is successful, class of the test inherits from StaticLiveServerTestCase. But when i call a celery task from the `app_name.tasks.task_name.delay()`, obviously after importing it, I noticed that the tasks runs on the my celery worker container that is for the production app and makes the changes that the task is supposed to do in the test database, it does it in the production database.
I have tried multiple possible solutions, like adding this above the test class `@override_settings(CELERY_TASK_EAGER_PROPAGATES=True,CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True,BROKER_BACKEND='memory')`
also tried to starting celery_worker in the test's thread using the following in the setUpClass:

```
cls.celery_worker = start_worker(app,perform_ping_check=False) 

cls.celery_worker.__enter__()
```

and in tearDownCass:

```
cls.celery_worker.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

and get this following error:

```
    ERROR/MainProcess] pidbox command error: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 104, in dispatch
    reply = handle(method, arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 126, in handle_cast
    return self.handle(method, arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 120, in handle
    return self.handlers[method](self.state, **arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/control.py", line 279, in enable_events
    if dispatcher.groups and 'task' not in dispatcher.groups:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

But even though this error is encountered, the changes in the production database still happen.
I am missing something, can anyone help me with how to make celery task make changes in test database.
Am i following a bad practice? I just hope that i can make my selenium fill the forms required for testing and the celery tasks do their job and update the database after some processing and i can assert them in the test class.

 Thank you, any help will be highly appreciated.

NOTE: The celery tasks are nested, i.e they call each other via .delay() or .apply_async() calls.

Comment: Are you able to solve the problem ? I encountered this issue somehow after some update of my requirements.txt(I suspect)

Comment: @ZhenshanJin Unfortunately, i didnt find any solution to this, ended up scrapping this idea :(

Comment: not sure my error is completely the same as yours but the error message is the same.  The problem with mine is that I enabled the celery flower but I also have `--without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat`. So my solution is to remove `--without-heartbeat` and add `--task-events`.